# Running @Preview on Emulator does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am starting to learn Jetpack Compose. I made this boilerplate code

```kotlin
package com.example.jeepni

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.jeepni.ui.theme.JeepniTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MainActivityLayout()
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun MainActivityLayout() {
    Greeting("new")
}
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $android!")
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MainActivityLayout()
}
```

When I try to click the run @Preview icon

[image]

the app will not run.

It gives me this error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Kyle\AndroidStudioProjects\JeepNi!\app\build\intermediates\compile_app_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar!/app/build/intermediates/compile_app_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar!/META-INF/app_debug.kotlin_module
```

This is the compiler error message:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'
```

I tried cleaning and rebuilding. I tried invalidating caches and restarting. Neither solution works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with composable function

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $android!")
}
```

change the string format to $name

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}
```